# How to disable generating controllers and views with CLI batch command for Giiant?

Tags: yii2, gii, yii2-giiant

I am using the command line for generating models with giiant, like this:

```
yii batch
```

What do I put into the application configuration or command line options to disable generating views and controllers?

I tried looking at the source of [BatchController](https://github.com/schmunk42/yii2-giiant/blob/master/src/commands/BatchController.php) to see if there are options for that, but I can't find any.

Comment: You want to generate only the Models?

Comment: @gmc Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: Then use `yii gii/giiant-model` ([source](https://github.com/schmunk42/yii2-giiant/blob/master/docs/25-cli-commands.md))

Comment: @gmc How do I do that? When I run it, it asks me to provide table name and model class. What should I put into application configuration so it does the same as `yii batch`, but without generating views and models?

Comment: `yii gii/giiant-model --tableName=user` (for `user` table)

Comment: @gmc I have tens of tables I need models for. Am I supposed to write a script that calls `yii gii/giant-model --tableName=$table` over a list of all of my tables? Isn't that already automated in some way, like in `batch`?

Comment: You can use the wildcard character: `--tableName=tbl_*` will create a model for each table starting with `tbl_`

Comment: @gmc I need to provide a list of specific tables. I can't provide `*`, because there are tables in the database that I do and don't want to have models for. With the configuration for `BatchController`, that is easily done with setting `tables` array. I don't see a way to do so with the `tableName` parameter for `gii/giiant-model`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the batch command

```
yii giiant-batch/models
```

will create only models and skip CRUDs.
There's also

```
yii giiant-batch/cruds
```

The default command

```
yii giiant-batch
```

runs both.